Sequential compactness of a sequence of curves of Borel probability measures
$
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supp}{supp}
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\bD}{\mathbb{D}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\cA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\cD}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\cE}{\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\cG}{\mathcal{G}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\sD}{\mathscr{D}}
\newcommand{\sE}{\mathscr{E}}
\newcommand{\sG}{\mathscr{G}}
\newcommand{\sH}{\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\sK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathscr{P}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\andd}{\quad \text{and} \quad}
\newcommand{\qtext}{\quad\text}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$
Let $\sP_2 (\bR^d)$ be the space of Borel probability measure on $\bR^d$ with finite second moment.

We denote by $M_2 (\nu) := \int_{\bR^d} |x|^2 \diff \nu (x)$ the second moment of $\nu \in \sP_2 (\bR^d)$. We denote by $W_2$ the $2$-Wasserstein metric on $\sP_2 (\bR^d)$.

We denote by $\rightharpoonup$ the weak convergence in $\sP_2 (\bR^d)$, i.e., $\nu_n \rightharpoonup \nu$ in $\sP_2 (\bR^d)$ if and only if $\int_{\bR^d} f \diff \nu_n \to \int_{\bR^d} f \diff \nu$ for every $f \in C_b (\bR^d)$. Correspondingly, we denote by $\tau_{\mathrm w}$ the topology that $\rightharpoonup$ induces on $\sP_2 (\bR^d)$.


For each $n \in \bN^*$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, let $\mu^n_t \in \sP_2 (\bR^d)$. We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and assume that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{t \in [0, 1]} \sup_{n \in \bN^*} M_2 (\mu^n_t) + \sup_{n \in \bN^*} \sup_{\substack{s,t \in [0, 1] \\ s \neq t}} \frac{W_2 (\mu^n_t, \mu^n_s)}{|t-s|^\alpha} < \infty.
\end{equation}
Then for each $t \in [0, 1]$, the sequence $(\mu^n_t)_{n \in \bN^*}$ has compact closure in $\tau_{\mathrm w}$.

Are there $(\mu_t)_{t \in [0, 1]} \subset \sP_2 (\bR^d)$ and a sub-sequence $(n_k)_{k \in \bN^*}$ such that for each $t \in [0, 1]$:
\begin{equation}
\mu^{n_k}_t \rightharpoonup \mu_t
\quad \text{as} \quad k \to \infty.
\end{equation}

Thank you for your elaboration.

Are you assuming some continuity for $\mu_{t}$ in $t$?

@Asaf I am willing to assume such a continuity condition. Please see my edit.

Errr... Isn't this an immediate application af the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem?

@Akira so, is this Arzelà-Ascoli in the end, or not? I'm pretty damn sure it is, so I'm just checking on any progress here?

@leomonsaingeon you are right! I am dumb...

Here are some ideas, but I did not have the time to check every detail.
Let $T \subset [0,1]$ be countable and dense. Using a diagonal sequence argument, one can find a subsequence such that
$$
\mu_n^{n_k} \rightharpoonup \mu_t
$$
for all $t \in T$.
Using your continuity assumption,
$$
T \ni t \mapsto \mu_t
$$
should be Hölder continuous.
Consequently, it should be possible to extend it to all of $[0,1]$
and to conclude with the desired convergence.

This is exactly the classical proof of the Arzelà-Ascoli theorem!
